# Encrypt number data in Oracle

Tags: oracle, security, encryption, oracle10g

I am now using Oracle 10g (10.0.2)
I want to encrypt some columns in my table with data type is number because some securities, is there any simple way to do it?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I'd take a look into [DBMS_CRYPTO](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/appdev.102/b14258/d_crypto.htm).

According to the link, DBMS_CRYPTO *provides an interface to encrypt and decrypt stored data, and can be used in conjunction with PL/SQL programs running network communications. It provides support for several industry-standard encryption and hashing algorithms, including the Advanced Encryption Standard (AES) encryption algorithm. AES has been approved by the National Institute of Standards and Technology (NIST) to replace the Data Encryption Standard (DES).*

Alternatively, you might want to look into [Transparent Data Encryption](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/network.102/b14268/asotrans.htm) (for which you need a seperate licence and the Enterprise Edition).